# Excel vba print

Tags: excel, vba

I have four columns in excel sheet. I have to compare third column with fourth coulmn and if the value of third column exceeds fourth column then i have to print all the three colums value. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why does this have a [visual-studio] tag ("Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality, not just a question regarding your code.")?  Should that be a [vb.net] tag?  And if so, why would you use VB.Net when you could just use VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Create a fifth column in the sheet labeled `third > fourth`.

Type following code in fifth column first row and copy throughout (`E1`). `C1` is first row third column, `D1` is first row fourth column.

```
=IF(C1>D1,TRUE)
```

Click on Sort in Toolbar and select only TRUE fields in E column.

Hide all columns you don't want to print.

Print the results.